# How to resolve focus snatching issue in Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-resources

**Background**

Development Tool: Android Studio 2.1.3

Device: Android OS Ver. 4.4.2

I have an Activity with multiple Views. I wanted to focus a certain view (`editText1` in this case) programatically based on user's previous actions. So I employed `View.requestFocus()` for this. Before this, I have set `focusable` and `focusableInThouchMode` of `editText1` to `true` XML design file:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".15"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:text="1"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

Ideally the scenario would be: If user has checked a certain `myCheckBox` before current action, move focus to `dditText1`, if else, return.

```
if(myCheckBox.isChecked()){
   editText1.selectAll();
   if(adet.requestFocusFromTouch()) {
       Log.i(General.LOG_TAG, "editText1 has focus");
       InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       imm.showSoftInput(editText1, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
   }
   return;
}
```

But In reality, some other View snatches focus instantly from `editText1`. I can even see that `editText1` got focus and have selected a text inside it for an instant. Also, I can see in log that editText1 got focus.

My activity contains a LinearLayout and all other Views(CheckBox, EditText, ListView etc.) are inside it. Also I have set `focusable` and `focusableInThouchMode` to `false` for other views than `editText1`

**Question**

How can I prevent other views than my `editText` from getting/snatching focus in my scenario?

Is there an alternative approach for what I am trying to do here?

Comment: Try using bringToFront on the View programatically. See if it helps. It worked for me in my custom arrayadapter layout whoch had multiple Textviews and Buttons.

Comment: @VikingPingvin, I tried `bringToFront`, result are same.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set `android:focusable="false"` for the components that should not get focused. Not sure I got your question right.